# Qt using shared COM Object

Tags: qt, dll, com

I have an shared dll file (COM, registered with regsvr32.exe) written by (I think with delphi) 3rd party company. But I havent .lib or any header file about this library. This library have a few objects, interfaces and functions. I can't find how to use exported objects, interfaces and functions on internet. Can anybody explain this with example? I can use this library with c# with success.

EDIT:

I think, I must use this http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/activeqt-dumpcpp.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the [`QAxContainer` classes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qaxcontainer.html).

> The QAxContainer module is a Windows-only extension for accessing
>   ActiveX controls and COM objects.

Also check the [Using ActiveX Controls and COM in Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/activeqt-container.html) page from the `Qt` documentation

Comment: I have read already. There something misunterstood. Do I have to wrap all objects and others (enums, interfaces etc.) with QAxObject like C# interop?

Comment: Check this tutorial : http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Using_ActiveX_Object_in_QT

Comment: I saw this tutorial too. But accessing objects member with     QAxObject* rows = sheet->querySubObject( "Rows" ); in this tutorial. I dont want this. Ex: Customer class defined in COM object, it have a property Name and an enum CustomerType . I want to use this class properly. May be I will use inheritance. Is this possible?

Comment: Once you create a QAxObject you can get its properties and interface by calling getDocumentation. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qaxbase.html#generateDocumentation You will see that you have access to all its membets. If you subclass it you can hide the accessing member functions you dont like